# saving base64 encoded images to .csv file changes string

Tags: python, image, encoding, base64, save

I'm using this script to batch encode local images to dataframe:

```
images_dir = "datasets/opensea.com/bored_apes/bayc/"
apes['image']=''

# iterate through dataframe to encode local image
for index, row in apes.iterrows():
    # retrieve image file from local folder
    with open(f"{images_dir}{'ape'}{row['id']}{'.png'}", "rb") as image_file:
        #encode it
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        #save the encoded image in the dataframe
        apes['image'].loc[index] = encoded_image
```

Then I can retrieve the image from dataframe with this:

```
# request an nft image from dataframe by id
b64_nft = apes[apes['id']==222].image.item()
nft_data = base64.b64decode(b64_nft)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(nft_data))
img_array = np.array(image)
plt.imshow(img_array)
```

as a test:

```
len(apes[apes['id']==222].image.item())
```

outputs 155072.
When I save the file using:

```
apes.to_csv('apes.csv',index=False)
```

the length of string in file is changed:

```
len(apes[apes['id']==222].image.item())
```

outputs 155075.

Obviously my decoding script :

```
b64_nft = apes[apes['id']==222].image.item()
nft_data = base64.b64decode(b64_nft).decode('utf-8')
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(nft_data))
img_array = np.array(image)
plt.imshow(img_array)
```

gives an error: "Error: Invalid base64-encoded string"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.